# SSIS error when importing excel date column and feeding to Slowly Changing Dimension

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, bids

I'm hoping someone that has come across this can help me out because I'm pulling my hair out here.

I have an excel sheet that has a bunch of columns, one of them being a date column. When I use an Excel Source and link it to a Slowly Changing Dimension transformation everything goes great until I click the last button to configure the component and then I get the following message. The date column is coming from excel as DB_DATE type and the database column is date. I've tried doing a data conversion and a derived column to coerce the date but still no love. Any ideas?

Here is the error:

> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: The component view is
>   unavailable. Make sure the component view has been created.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [Slowly Changing Dimension [26]]: The input column "input column "TargetDate" (94)" cannot be mapped to
>   external column "external column "TargetDate" (87)" because they have
>   different data types. The Slowly Changing Dimension transform does not
>   allow mapping between column of different types except for DT_STR and
>   DT_WSTR.

I have also successfully used a standard OLEDB destination with this same excel sheet with a date field and it imported the whole sheet fine so I can't see why it's having an issue using the Slowly Changing Dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the advice of some SSIS rock stars I've met, you're probably better avoiding the SCD transformation and rolling your own. That you're getting a standard OLEDB destination to work leads leads me to this conclusion. The advice I received against the SCD transforamtion is based on performance. As I recall OLEDB Commands are generated, and that gets you into row-by-row slowness.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Had to get this done today so instead I ended up importing into a staging table and use the t-sql MERGE command to update/insert the records.